# Using React LinkedStateMixin for text input doesn't re-render as expected

Tags: javascript, forms, backbone.js, reactjs

Here's the render function for one of my react components:

```
render: function() {
    var valueLink = this.linkState.value;
    var handleBlur = function(e) {
        valueLink.requestChange(e.target.value);
    };
    return (
        <input
            type="text"
            defaultValue={valueLink}
            onBlur={handleBlur}
        />
    );
}
```

I'm using backbone-react. After setting an attribute on the model, this component calls its `render` function. The backbone model gets set properly, but the input field doesn't render the value that was set on the model.

Basically when the `render` function gets called after the `valueLink.value` changes, the input field doesn't reflect this change.

I've tried using `value` instead of `defaultValue` but that makes it a controlled component.

I also don't want to use `valueLink` as that sets state for every key press whereas I only what to trigger that for onBlur.

Any ideas? (Please let me know if you need more info.)

Answer (score 0):

From React docs

> LinkedStateMixin adds a method to your React component called
>   linkState(). linkState()     returns a ReactLink object which contains
>   the current value of the React state and a callback to change it.

In your example, instead of this.linkState.value, pass a state variable to linkState. Ex this.linkState('message')

```
var Component = React.createClass({
    mixins: [React.addons.LinkedStateMixin],
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {message: 'Hello!'};
    },
    render: function () {
        var valueLink = this.linkState('message');
        var handleBlur = function(e) {
            valueLink.requestChange(e.target.value);
        };
        return (
        <div>
        <input
            type="text"
            defaultValue={valueLink.value}
            onBlur={handleBlur}
        />
        <br />
        {this.state.message}
        </div>
    );
    }
});

React.render(<Component />, document.body);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kirana/ne3qamq7/12/